# Polar area and do I need absolute value signs?

Tags: calculus, integration, area, polar-coordinates

Imagine a curve such as
$$r=\sqrt{\sin x}$$

The area over $(0,\pi)$ would be calculated as follows:

$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sin x}^2dx=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}|{\sin x}|dx, not \int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}{\sin x}dx$$
correct?

Comment: Since $\sin x$ is nonnegative on $[0,\pi]$, you can remove the absolute value symbol.

Comment: I just realized that as i posted the question! Crap, i feel really stupid. Thanks though.